# How do you open your extensions popup programatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension which has a popup. I want to be able to open it with both the browser action icon and with a keyboard shortcut. I'm able to route the keyup event to my controller, but I'm not sure how to actually open the popup programatically. Is there an event I can fire or an API I can call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently not possible, sorry.